# How a transaction proves its ownership of the its source, which can be one or multiple unspent output?

Tags: transactions, signature

I read the following from the book << Mastering Bitcoin >>

> "As you may notice, the transaction contains an empty scriptSig because we haven’t signed it yet. Without a signature, this transaction is meaningless, we haven’t yet proven that we own the address from which the unspent output is sourced."

I am wondering how a signature can prove that this transaction owns the address from which the unspent output is sourced?

Answer (score 3):

Assume you understand how [public-key cryptography](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public-key_cryptography) works. In short, one can verify the ownership of an address by checking the signature. A valid signature can only be generated by the private key owner.

The detail of signature verification in Bitcoin is described [here](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Transaction#Pay-to-PubkeyHash)

Without digging into the details, `OP_xxx` are stack operations. For example, `OP_DUP` is to duplicate top of the stack. Basically it

- first hashes the public key by operation `OP_HASH160` and check if the result is identical to `pubKeyHash` by operation `OP_EQUALVERIFY`
- then verifies `sig` and `pubKey` by operation `OP_CHECKSIG`

You can read more about `OP_CHECKSIG` [here](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/OP_CHECKSIG)

Comment: Please elaborate on what the links explain in the answer as well. As it stands, this answer is not helpful if the links stop working.

Answer (score 2):

The ownership is proven for each input by providing a valid signature in the `scriptSig` field. If one of the signatures is missing, the whole transaction is invalid.

The `scriptPubKey` for each output in the example you provided is locked to a Bitcoin address. A Bitcoin address is, in a nutshell, a hash of a public key. So, in order to provide a valid signature, the secret key belonging to the same key pair of the public key referred in each input is required.